# .htaccess fail if X-Header not present for png, gif and jpg's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I'm trying to filter requests for certain web assets (png, gif, jpg, jpeg and mp4 files) based on a specific x-header/value, and fail if not present in the request.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Pull} !secretkey
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|mp4)$ - [F]
```

It is expected to throw a 403/forbidden error for these file types, if a request does not contain the x-header/secretkey pair, regardless the full path to the file on the website.

I have tried several variations in my .htaccess file, but for *.png, *.gif, *.jpg and *.jpeg files it only works if the files reside in the website's root. However, the same rule works for *.mp4 files, regardless of where they are located (which is how it should work for all the file types in the list).

The site uses mod_pagespeed.

Answer (score 1):

Since Pagespeed is deployed on this server, the .htaccess directives for rewriting the same asset types doesn't work. Here is one way I tried to handle the issue (by updating virtual host configuration file):

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  <If "req('X-Pull') != 'secretkey'">
    ModPagespeed off
  </If>
  <Else>
    ModPagespeed on
  </Else>
  ...
</IfModule>
```

I also moved the rewrites to the virtual host configuration file due to the "significant per-request overhead from processing .htaccess files", as noted in the Pagespeed documentation.